How to copy all instances of a value across multiple sheets, given that it fulfills certain circumstances using VBA?
I have an existing code that cycles through multiple sheets and copies rows with a value in column B and D, but P being empty, to a report sheet. How can I go about getting it to search for all identical values in column D across all sheets and copying to the report sheet while keeping the original code intact? EX: rows 1, 2, and 3 on sheet 1 fulfill the requirements and will be copied to the report sheet. Row 1 on sheet 2 does not fulfill the requirements, but the cell D1 is the same as D1 on sheet 1. I would like it to copy all 4 rows.
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim srcSheets As Sheets: Set srcSheets = wb.Sheets(Array("sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4, sheet5"))

Dim rptSheet As Worksheet: Set rptSheet = wb.Sheets("Report")
Dim rptCell As Range: Set rptCell = rptSheet.Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Dim srcSheet As Object, srcRange As Range, srcRow As Range
    
For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
    If TypeOf srcSheet Is Worksheet Then
        Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A5:N358")
        For Each srcRow In srcRange.Rows
            If Len(CStr(srcRow.Columns("B").Value)) > 0 And _
               Len(CStr(srcRow.Columns("P").Value)) = 0 And _
               Len(CStr(srcRow.Columns("D").Value)) > 0 Then
                srcRow.Copy Destination:=rptCell
                Set rptCell = rptCell.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next srcRow
    End If
Next srcSheet


Collect all of the unique "D" values for copied rows, then run a second loop to search for those values, excluding the rows you already copied.

Collect all of the unique "D" values for copied rows, then run a second loop to search for those values, excluding the rows you already copied.
Something like this:
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, srcSheets As Sheets, rptSheet As Worksheet, rptCell As Range
    Dim srcSheet As Object, srcRange As Range, srcRow As Range, run As Long
    Dim dict As Object, dVal
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'case-insentive
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcSheets = wb.Sheets(Array("sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4, sheet5"))
    
    Set rptSheet = wb.Sheets("Report")
    Set rptCell = rptSheet.Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    For run = 1 To 2
        For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
            If TypeOf srcSheet Is Worksheet Then
                Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A5:N358")
                For Each srcRow In srcRange.Rows
                    dVal = CStr(srcRange.Columns("D").Value)
                    If CopyRow(srcRow) Then 'first run copies valid rows
                        If run = 1 Then
                            CopyToNext srcRow, rptCell
                            dict(dVal) = True 'remember colD value
                        End If
                    Else
                        If run = 2 Then 'copying D matches for otherwise invalid rows on second run...
                            If dict.Exists(dVal) Then
                                CopyToNext srcRow, rptCell
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next srcRow
            End If
        Next srcSheet
    Next run
End Sub

'does a row meet the criteria to be copied?
Function CopyRow(rw As Range) As Boolean
    'Nested If is faster - may not need to read all 3 cells
    If Len(rw.Columns("B").Value) > 0 Then
        If Len(rw.Columns("P").Value) = 0 Then
             CopyRow = Len(rw.Columns("D").Value) > 0
        End If
    End If
End Function

'helper sub
Sub CopyToNext(ByRef rwToCopy As Range, ByRef destCell As Range)
    rwToCopy.Copy destCell
    Set destCell = destCell.Offset(1) 'next paste location
End Sub

